# I can't show the button pressed on the GLCD ST7920?

Tags: keypad

I have a small project that i want to show my keypad pressed on my GLCD but when i pressed keypad, even on serial it is fines but on GLCD it can't show my characters. Could you tell me what the problem and what should i do to solve!.  my GLCD library is BasicGLCD!

```
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <basicGLCD.h>
basicGLCD GLCD;
/*long four = 0;
long three = 0;
long two = 0;
long one = 0;
*/
int adress = 0; // gia tri dia chi luu du lieu
const byte rows = 4; //so hang
const byte columns = 4; // so cot
 
int holdDelay = 100; // thoi gian tre de xem la nhan 1 nut de tranh nhieu~
int n = 3; // 
int state = 0; // neu state=0 khong nhan, state=1 nhan thoi gian nho , state = 2 nhan giu lau
char key = 0;
int i=1; 
//dinh nghia cac gia tri tra ve
char hexaKeys[rows][columns] =
{
  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'*', '0', '#', 'D'},
};
 
byte rowPins[rows] = {4, 5, 6, 7}; // cách nói chan Arduino
byte columnPins[columns] = {12, 13, 2, 3};// cách nói chan Arduino
 
//cài đặt thư viện keypad
Keypad keypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(hexaKeys), rowPins, columnPins, rows, columns);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);//bật serial, baudrate 9600
  
 // GLCD.setCursor(4, 0);
  //GLCD.sendString("WELCOME....");
  

  //////
  GLCD.setDataPins(23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37);
  GLCD.setRSPin(A2);
  GLCD.setCSPins(A0, A1);
  GLCD.setENPin(A4);
  GLCD.setRWPin(A3);
  if(GLCD.init() != 1) {
    Serial.println("You have to set all pins");
    return 0;
  }
  else {
  GLCD.sendString("   WELCOME  ");
  GLCD.setCursor(10, 0);
  delay(500);
  GLCD.clear();}
  //////////////////////////////////////////
 
 
 
 GLCD.setCursor(0, 1);
 GLCD.sendString("Loai IVT: ");
 GLCD.setCursor(0, 2);
 GLCD.sendString("TG mau : ");
 GLCD.setCursor(0, 3);
 GLCD.sendString("CSCD :");
  

}
//////////////////////////////////////////
void loop() 
{  
  char temp = keypad.getKey();
  if ((int)keypad.getState() ==  PRESSED) {
    if (temp != 0) {
      key = temp;
    }
    
    //xem kq
  if(temp)
    {if(temp == '+')
    {GLCD.clear();} 
    if(temp == '=')
    {i=i+1;}
    GLCD.setPage(RIGHT);
    GLCD.setCursor(5,i);
    GLCD.sendData(temp); 
    ;
    }
 delay(500);
}
}
```

Comment: do you see the word WELCOME on the LCD?

Comment: Yes, it shows WELCOME first and "Loai IVT", "TG mau","CSCD " after, but when i press keypad to sent the number in each parameters  but it doesn't work.  it just shows any dot in the GLCD

Comment: add debugging code to your sketch ... use `Serial.print()` to determine what the code is doing

Comment: Well , in serial i don't see anything, the keypad code is from example it work well when indepentdent but when it has GLCD , i can't see anything on Serial monitor